# Select some fileds from object in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Hi I need to select only particular fields from object.
something like this using mongoid

```
User.select(:name, :email).all
```

please help me.

I don’t know why only is not working for me if i use as_json on it.

```
User.only(:name, :email).all.as_json
```

is throwing attributes missing error.

Comment: do you want to select the name and email value or just want to put in all name and email in an array

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting a bunch of `nil`s and default values in the returned objects that you're not expecting?

Comment: Yes I am getting nil values in other fields which i am not calling.
and I am using as_json on it User.only(:name, :email).all.as_json it is throwing missing attributes error.

Comment: I do not get an error when I add ".as_json" to the queries in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `only` method works for me. Are you certain that mongo is returning a value for the other parameters? The attributes should still exist for those extra parameters, but they should be assigned to nil instead.

```
1.9.3-p194 :011 > Retailer.only(:description).all.first
    => #<Retailer _id: 1, description: "WALMART", aliases: nil> 
1.9.3-p194 :012 > Retailer.all.first
    => #<Retailer _id: 1, description: "WALMART", aliases: ["WALMART.COM", "WAL-MART"]>
```

Comment: Actually I am using as_json to the method. so, it is throwing missing attributes error